# Angular: history.state.data returns undefined instead of the last set data object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table of orders..each table row represents an order entity and when the user clicks on a specific row, it should redirect to a new view with the details of the clicked order .These two components are not parent and child and I want to pass data about clicked order row to the navigated page..
I tried the following approach

```
 <tr *ngFor="let order of allOrders" routerLink="../orderdetails" [state]=”{data:order}”>
                <td>{{order.orderRef}}</td>
                <td>{{order.receiptRef}}</td>
                <td>{{order.customer}}</td>
                <td>{{order.orderDate}}</td>
                <td>{{order.salesMan}}</td>
                <td>{{order.total}}</td>
                <td>{{order.status}}</td>
                <td>{{order.session}}</td>
                <td>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

This causes view to navigate to `Orderdetails`

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(history.state)
    console.log(history.state.data);
  }
```

Inside the ngOnInit() `console.log(history.state)` logs `{navigationId: 1}`
but `console.log(history.state.data)` logs `undefined`.

Why am I getting `undefined` and not the data I set on the `state` ?

How can I access the data I passed in to the `state` property?

Comment: Can u provide more code for the `component` which has `history.state` in it. I think you are not doing it right but I need to see entire code to help you fix it

Comment: @ShashankVivek  `history.state` is browser's window object's field..I didn't define it .. I was following https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255

Comment: Can u try the updated answer and let me know

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Upon some research, I found that **state doesnt work on non-anchor elements**.

To solve the issue, On routing programatically we can use state:

**orders.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let order of allOrders" (click)="onNavToOrderDetails(order)">
   <td>{{order.orderRef}}</td>
   <td>{{order.receiptRef}}</td>
   ....
</tr>
```

**orders.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
   private router: Router
) {}

onNavToOrderDetails(order: Order) {
   this.router.navigate(['routetodetailscomponent'], { state: {data: order} });
}
```

**orderDetails.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   console.log(history.state)
   console.log(history.state.data);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this while also opening the page in a new tab? I am attempting to use this method to transmit complex objects between components..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. History.state was simply empty when i navigated to next component. The reason for that was that i accidentally executed a

`_router.navigate([] {relativeTo: this._activatedRoute, queryParams: {search: searchqueryparams}, queryParamsHandling: 'merge'})`

via a subscription in the constructor at pageload, which was there to persist any searchqueryparams to the url.
It seems like the router.navigate overrides the old history state even when the component stays the same. So simply saving the old state before navigating again solved the issue for me.